# Correlated Stochastic Processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let say, I have 2 stochastic processes:
$$\begin{align}
dS_1 &= \left( r - q_1 \right)S_1 dt + \sigma_1 S_1 dW_1
\\
dS_2 &= \left( r - q_2 \right)S_2 dt + \sigma_2 S_2 dW_2
\end{align}$$
The correlation between these 2 processes is $\rho$. Now I define 2 new processes as:
$$\begin{align}
x_1 = \sigma_1 \log S_2 + \sigma_2 \log S_1
\\
x_2 = \sigma_1 \log S_2 - \sigma_2 \log S_1
\end{align}$$

As per Hull's book, these processes $x_1, x_2$ are uncorrelated with standard deviation $\sigma_1 \sigma_2 \sqrt{2 \left( 1+\rho \right)}$ and $\sigma_1 \sigma_2 \sqrt{2 \left( 1-\rho \right)}$ respectively.

How can I show this result?

Comment: What have you tried? Also, the correlation $\rho$ is between the Brownian Motions $W_1$ and $W_2$ correct?

Comment: I am able to derive the $dt$ term, but not the `volatility` part. Apologies if this is very trivial question. Any pointer is appreciated.

Comment: If $S_i$ is log-normal, then $\log S_i$ is normal. Have you tried computing the covariance between $x_1$ and $x_2$?

Answer (score 3):

I have the impression the expressions in your question miss the time term $t$, though this does not change much. Define for $i,j\in\{1,2\}$:
$$\begin{align}
s_i(t)&=\log S_i(t)
\\
y_{i,j}(t)&=\sigma_is_j(t)
\end{align}$$
Then:
$$\begin{align}
V(y_{i,j}(t))&=\sigma_i^2V(s_j(t))
\\
&=\sigma_i^2V(\sigma_jW_j(t))
\\
&=\sigma_i^2\sigma_j^2t
\\
&=V(y_{j,i}(t))
\end{align}$$
Moreover:
$$\begin{align}
C(y_{1,2}(t),y_{2,1}(t))&=\sigma_1\sigma_2C(s_2(t),s_1(t))
\\
&=\sigma_1^2\sigma_2^2C(W_2(t),W_1(t))
\\
&=\sigma_1^2\sigma_2^2\rho t
\end{align}$$
Hence:
$$\begin{align}
&V(x_1(t))=\sigma_1^2\sigma^2_2t+\sigma_2^2\sigma_1^2t+2\sigma^2_1\sigma^2_2\rho t=\sigma_1^2\sigma_2^22(1+\rho)t
\\
&V(x_2(t))=\sigma_2^2\sigma^2_1t+\sigma_1^2\sigma_2^2t-2\sigma^2_1\sigma^2_2\rho t=\sigma_1^2\sigma_2^22(1-\rho)t
\end{align}$$
Finally, by bi-linearity and symmetry of covariance:
$$\begin{align}
C(x_1(t),x_2(t))&=C(y_{1,2}(t)+y_{2,1}(t),y_{1,2}(t)-y_{2,1}(t))
\\
&=V(y_{1,2}(t))-C(y_{1,2}(t),y_{2,1}(t))+C(y_{2,1}(t),y_{1,2}(t))-V(y_{2,1}(t))
\\
&=V(y_{1,2}(t))-V(y_{2,1}(t))
\\
&=0
\end{align}$$
$x_1$ and $x_2$ are uncorrelated $-$ note that for normally-distributed random variables, null correlation also implies independence.

Comment: Many thanks. Is there any way on how to generalise this for `n` initial correlated stochastic processed for $S_t$?

Comment: Generally, you can express a specific covariance structure in your asset process as $CdW$ with $C$ the lower cholesky decomposition of the covariant empire matrix. I think that you may be able to use its inverse $C^{-1}$ to weight the assets in order to de-correlate the assets.